# Search and replace NaN and inf in MATLAB array in the fastest way

Tags: matlab

Preferably without loop as I can do this with loop and I also suspect it is slow. Maybe?

Say `k = [1 1 1 1 3 3 inf 12 3 NaN 13 8 8 8 8 8 NaN 9 9 9];`

If the entries of `k` are `NaN` or `inf`, I wish to replace it with `5`.

How can I do this?

Comment: @beaker is that the fastest?

Comment: I haven't heard of anything that's likely to be faster.

Comment: @beaker can I check two condition? k( isnan(k)||isinf(k) ) = 5; matlab disallows this.

Comment: That should work. What error are you getting?

Comment: @beaker Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to logical scalar
values.

Comment: Ugh. Try the single `|`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [isnan](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isnan.html) and [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1):

```
k = [1 1 1 1 3 3 34 12 3 NaN 13 8 8 8 8 8 NaN 9 9 9];
k( isnan(k) ) = 5;
```

Comment: can I check two condition? `k( isnan(k)||isinf(k) ) = 5;` matlab disallows this.

Comment: Yes, but with a single `|`. `||` is only for scalars.